# arduino push a char into char array right shift the entire array but all char change to the same one

Tags: arrays, arduino, char, push, shift

I push a char into a char array in Arduino. Here is the code:

```cpp
#define q_length 10
char * queue[q_length] = {"10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"};
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
int in = 0;
void loop() {
  char buf[60];
  strcpy(buf, "--");
  char ii[20];
  itoa(in, ii, 10);
  strcat(buf, ii);

  for (byte i = q_length; i > 0; i--){
    queue[i] = queue[i - 1];
  }
  queue[0] = buf;
  in ++;

  for (byte i = 0; i < q_length; i++) {
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(":");
    Serial.println(queue[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("==========");
  delay(1000);

}
```

and output

```
0:--0
1:10
2:9
3:8
4:7
5:6
6:5
7:4
8:3
9:2
==========
0:--1
1:--1
2:10
3:9
4:8
5:7
6:6
7:5
8:4
9:3
==========
0:--2
1:--2
2:--2
3:10
4:9
5:8
6:7
7:6
8:5
9:4
```

As you can see, every time I push a new one the other char I just pushed change became the new one.

I want to push the new char into the char array index 0, right shift the entire array, and just change the index 0 char. Not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

`queue` is an array of the pointer to the string.
Assignments between it's elements merely duplicate the pointer to the string.
You are just pushing one identical `buf` address after another.

And one thing I would like to point out, although it is not related to the main topic.

```
for (byte i = q_length; i > 0; i--){
    queue[i] = queue[i - 1];
}
```

The index on the `queue` should be from 0 to (q_length-1), but you have accessed beyond that range.

---

In response to the comment, I present an alternative.

However, I do not have the Arduino development environment here, so I show the general C code. You can read it as you see fit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define q_length 10
#define bufsize 5
char queue[q_length][bufsize] = {"10","9","8","7","6","5","4","3","2","1"};
int in = 0;
void loop() {
    char buf[bufsize];
    sprintf(buf, "--%d", in);

    for (int i = q_length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        strcpy(queue[i], queue[i - 1]);
    }
    strcpy(queue[0], buf);
    in ++;

    for (int i = 0; i < q_length; i++) {
        printf("%d:%s\n", i, queue[i]);
    }
    printf("==========\n");
}

int main()
{
    loop();
    loop();
    loop();
}
```

Comment: thank you for point out the issue.  I've thought that way you said. but anyidea I can push the different buf address. I do not know how to google it.

Comment: Added to the answer.